# How to call a function in an elisp program, and follow the interactive path?

Tags: emacs, elisp, ispell

If I call `ispell-check-version` interactively (through <kbd>M-x</kbd>) it got this answer:

> @(#) International Ispell Version 3.3.02 12 Jun 2005, ispell.el 3.6 - 7-Jan-2003

Fine. Now let's say I want to call it from a program. I expect to get the same result. But the function behaves differently when not call interactively. Its documentation tells so, and indeed it does. Let's try in the `*scratch*` buffer (evaluated with <kbd>C-u C-x C-e</kbd>):

```
(ispell-check-version)
```

returns me : "/opt/local/lib" !! Not exepected.. How can I make the function behaves and the return the same result now that I call it "programatically" as when I was  calling it "interactively" please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call-interactively` is what you are looking for.

```
(call-interactively 'ispell-check-version)
```